# Are there any naming conventions for primary/entrant classes and their super classes?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have a question regarding naming conventions in C# that I don't think are covered in either the majority of the previously asked questions or the usual resources like the [MSDN Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx). The majority of existing naming conventions focus on frameworks and things to be consumed by other classes. This may be a bit different.

**What do you name the class where Main() resides? And how does it relate to its superclass?**

Let's say you're a fledgling programmer and you create a small application much like this site. You might do something like this.

```
// the title of the class happens to be the title of the project

namespace FogCreek {
  public class StackOverflow {
    public static Main() { ... }
  }
}
```

But then you decide to refactor your innards as you grow and create more Stack sites, each one occopying their own namespace.

```
namespace FogCreek.StackSites.StackOverflow {
  public class WhatDoICallThis : StackExchangeSite {
    public static Main() { ... }
  }
}

// elsewhere in another project...

namespace FogCreek {
  public class StackExchangeSite {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm hesitant to call it StackOverflow because it's full name be FogCreek.StackSites.StackOverflow.StackOverflow. Isn't that a bit redundant?

Also, should StackExchangeSite be in its own namespace within FogCreek? Or should it be "higher than" the projects that derive from it?

```
Company.Foobar.Widget
-> Company.Foobar.Widget.RoundWidget
-> Company.Foobar.Widget.SquareWidget

vs

Company.Foobar.Widget.BaseWidget
-> Company.Foobar.Widget.RoundWidget
-> Company.Foobar.Widget.SquareWidget
```

I don't favor the second option because I don't recall any extendable classes that use the word "Base".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you should rather leave it as is (typically called `Program`) and instead **favor composition over inheritance**.

The entry point it a static method, so there's absolutely no reason to create an inheritance tree that involves the class holding the Main method.